# Partial Differentiation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=???$$

I can differentiate it

$$\frac{d}{d y}(y-z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(y-z)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

But i don't know when it is *Partial*.

Comment: it is the same, consider z as constant

Comment: Or: Partial differentiation is differentiation with respect to a particular variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to do an ordinary differentiation of the function, you would actually get this:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}(y-z)^{1/2} = \frac12\left(1-\frac{dz}{dy}\right)(y-z)^{-1/2} \; .
$$

The partial derivative takes $z$ to be constant, and thus $\frac{dz}{dy}=0$, so that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y-z)^{1/2} = \frac12(y-z)^{-1/2} \; .
$$